# How do I get line breaks from mLab database to display on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, textarea

When a user adds an answer to a question, the answer is saved to mLab with /r/n.  I can not figure out how to display the answers with line breaks.
[Github Repo](https://github.com/daxapps/WebDevQnAs), 
[Live Site](http://webdevqnas.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Replace the `\r\n` with `<br />` tag when displaying as html. If you need to display it in textarea, there should be no need to do anything, it would show as a newline.

Comment: How do I replace /r/n with <br /> tag when displaying as html. I tried several ways with no success.

Comment: You can replace it using `String.replace`. e.g. if the answer is stored in a variable `answer`. Then do this: `let updatedAnswer = answer.replace(/\/r\/n/g, '<br />');` and use ouput `updatedAnswer` in your html.

Comment: Thank You, that helped me out.